# Should the functions folder for firebase cloud functions be within the (public) folder?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my website project should the functions folder be nested within the (public) folder or outside of it? Or as some other posts seem to suggest, the public should be nested within the functions?

I intent to use the functions only do do back end work, no refrences from the html, css, or js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you'd usually have something like:

```
functions
public (or source or something similar)
```

So `functions` is a sibling of the folder containing your public files.

The reason is that the `public` folder contains files where you want to share their raw contents with your users. For Cloud Functions that is often quite the opposite: while their outputs/results may be shown to users, you typically don't want to share the code.